# How to access element attribute whose display is none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access the attribute/value of 'schoolidx' that is not hidden, when add button is clicked; however I am having hard time accessing it.

Can someone guide me please? I am trying to get only "1", or "2", or "3" depending on which one is not hidden ("display: none;"). In this case, "1".

Tried different methods:

```
        let schoolIndex = $('#schoolTableBody > tr:not([style*="display: none"])').attr("schoolidx"),
            schoolIndex2 = $('tr').filter(function(){ return $(this).css("display") != "none";}).attr("schoolidx"),
            schoolIndex3 = $('tr').filter(function(){ return $(this).css("display") != "none";}).attr("schoolidx"),
            schoolIndex4 = $("#schoolTableBody > tr:visible")


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="schoolTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> </th>
        <th>School Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="schoolTableBody">
    <tr class="school-row" style="">
        <td><button id="addSchoolBtn" title="Add" style="width:50px"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sName" id="sName"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Country" id="Country"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr schoolidx="1" style="">
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="SK">SK</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="US">US</td>
    </tr>
    <tr schoolidx="1" style="">
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="JS">JS</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="US">US</td>
    </tr>
    <tr schoolidx="2" style="display: none;">
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="CAS">CAS</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="CA">CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr schoolidx="2" style="display: none;">
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="AM">AM</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="CA">CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr schoolidx="3" style="display: none;">
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="BAS">BAS</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="BR">BR</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You say you only want to get a number, yet you have four variables corresponding to all three numbers and a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to search by styling, perhaps you could add an 'active' class when you unhide a given row, and remove it when you hide it again.

You can then search using jQuery. `var schoolid = $("tr.active").prop("schoolidx");`

Have a look at [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). I assume you already have the ability to hide each row. Just add those two functions to that bit of code.

Comment: I think it is cleaner to depend on classname as you suggested

Comment: This just isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

Note that I have changed your 'attribute' to a valid [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

For the JS, we have to make sure we're only selecting the `tr`'s within the `tbody` but **not** the first `tr` as thats where the add button is.

Then do an `if()` within an `onclick` to check to see if the `display` is set to `none`

`<button>` aren't self closing, they require a `</button>`

```js
document.getElementById('addSchoolBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('#schoolTableBody tr:not(.school-row)').forEach(tr => {
    if (tr.style.display !== "none") alert(tr.dataset.schoolidx)
  })
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="schoolTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th>School Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="schoolTableBody">
    <tr class="school-row" style="">
      <td><button id="addSchoolBtn" title="Add" style="width:50px">Add</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sName" id="sName"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Country" id="Country"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-schoolidx="1" style="">
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="SK">SK</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="US">US</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-schoolidx="1" style="">
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="JS">JS</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="US">US</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-schoolidx="2" style="display: none;">
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="CAS">CAS</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="CA">CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-schoolidx="2" style="display: none;">
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="AM">AM</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="CA">CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-schoolidx="3" style="display: none;">
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="sName" value="BAS">BAS</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="Country" value="BR">BR</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```